# Adding Addition Tabs to TemplateRole

Tags: docusignapi

I have the DocuSign API working to pre-fill existing tabs on a template.  I am trying to add some additional tabs dynamically for the templaterole signers, but the tabs are not showing up.

Here is my code that I am working with.

```
string SigningGroupID = "12345";
string RoleName = "Test Signing Group"';
string TemplateId = "XXX-XX-XXXX-XXX";

List<TemplateRole> templateRoles = new List<TemplateRole>();
DocuSign.eSign.Model.Tabs tabs = new DocuSign.eSign.Model.Tabs();
List<Text> TextTabs = new List<Text>();

Text text = new Text();
text.TabLabel = "test_label";
text.XPosition = "100";
text.YPosition = "150";
TextTabs.Add(text);

if (TextTabs.Count > 0) tabs.TextTabs = TextTabs;

TemplateRole doc_signer = new TemplateRole
{
SigningGroupId = SigningGroupID,
RoleName = RoleName,
RoutingOrder = "1",
Tabs = tabs
};

templateRoles.Add(doc_signer);

EnvelopeDefinition envelope = new EnvelopeDefinition();
envelope.EmailSubject = "This is a test";
envelope.Status = "created";
envelope.TemplateId = TemplateId;
envelope.TemplateRoles = templateRoles;

EnvelopesApi envelopeApi = new EnvelopesApi(_apiClient.Configuration);
EnvelopeSummary results = envelopeApi.CreateEnvelope(AccountID, envelope);

Console.WriteLine(results.ToJson());
```

Do I need some additional items populated on the new Text object (e.g. TabID)?  I am not sure why this is not working.

Thanks
jlimited

Comment: Answered below. If it helped you out, be sure to upvote and accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. You're missing a few properties for your Text object. When you define your Text tab, be sure to connect it to the appropriate recipient, document, and page by specifying the following:

- text.documentId
- text.pageNumber
- text.recipientId
- text.xPosition
- text.yPosition
- text.tabLabel

To determine the three missing values, you can make a request to GET /templates, which will return to you the IDs. SDK method is [Templates:get](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Templates/Templates/get)

There are many more properties you can add, but you'll need these to get your tab to display properly.